# Accessing data in store from library angular

Tags: angular, typescript, ngrx, angular-library, angular14

I have ngrx store implemented in my main application which holds all the common data.

I am using custom angular libraries also in main application. How can i access the data available in store from the library.
I have created a selector in library and  imported the StoreModules as root and feature in library ngModules. Still i am not able to access the data from store.

Comment: Please provide some code examples to clarify your question. If applicable, share error messages that you are getting. Right now it's very hard to help you with your problem as we can't possibly start guessing what could be the cause